# Substitution in general double integral

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, substitution, wave-equation

Is possible to go from
$$\int_0^t\int_0^s f(x-ct+2cs-cr,r) \, \Bbb{d}r \, \Bbb{d}s$$
to
$$\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t\int_{x-c(t-z)}^{x+c(t-z)} f(y,z)\,\Bbb{d}y\,\Bbb{d}z,$$
where $c\in \Bbb{R}$, $x\in \Bbb{R}$, $t\gt 0$,
with some smart substitution or am I completely wrong? What I am trying to do is to get the general solution of the nonhomogenous 1D wave equation with zero initial conditions 
$$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=f(x,t), $$
$$u(x,0)=0,u_t(x,0)=0, $$
by solving an equivalent problem, which is system of two nonhomogenous transport equations
$$u_t+cu_x=v(x,t), $$
$$v_t-cv_x=f(x,t) $$
and now I am stuck with this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use Fubini's first, finding that your integral is equivalent to
$$
\int_0^t\int_r^tf(x-ct+2cs-cr,r)\mathrm ds\mathrm dr
$$
then perform your substitution
$$
y=x-ct+2cs-cr\implies \mathrm dy=2c\mathrm ds
$$
and your upper limit is 
$$
y=x+ct-cr=x+c(t-r)
$$
and your lower limit is
$$
y=x-ct+cr=x-c(t-r)
$$
yielding your final integral
$$
\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t\int_{x-c(t-r)}^{x+c(t-r)}f(y,r)\mathrm dy \mathrm dr
$$

Comment: Why is $\int_0^s$ equivalent to $\int_r^t$ ? Also, in the last integral you wrote, there should be $\Bbb{d}y$ instead of  $\Bbb{d}s$, right?

Comment: it is not, but the double integral is equivalent to the double integral I wrote. Try sketching the region and changing the order of integration

Comment: Yes I fixed a couple of typos that may have been confusing.

Comment: Ahh, I see it. Now it is clear. Thank you very much, sir.